# jQuery autocomplete renders SQL Array / not textbox selections

Tags: jquery, vb.net, wcf, autocomplete

trying to get basic jQuery autocomplete to work. Using SQL Server via WCF service in VS 2017. All appears good ... .aspx renders OK, enter 1 char in textbox, debug that .svc is firing, debug SQL function and see good data grab, debug jQuery and see via console log that array is returned, see via console that array reduces with every additional character entered in text box... but no list is ever produced on the page that allows for item selection. Strange.  Even ran it successfully with hard coded Country list and it worked fine. Including jQuery and HTML, not including .svc as that is confirmed to be returning accurate values.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindControls();
});

function BindControls() {
   $("#txtMembers1").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {

            var val = request.term;
            console.log(val);
            $.ajax({
                url: "searchMembers1.svc/getMembers",
                data: JSON.stringify({ sLookUP: val }),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item }
                    }))
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2    // MINIMUM 1 CHARACTER TO START WITH.
    }); 

   /* var Countries = ["ARGENTINA", "AUSTRALIA", "BRAZIL", "BELARUS", "BHUTAN", "CHILE"];

    // BIND ARRAY OF STRINGS WITH AUTOCOMPLETE FUNCTION.
    $("#txtMembers").autocomplete({ source: Countries }); */


}
```

HTML -------

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css" >
    .ui-autocomplete { max-height: 150px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; font-size: 9pt; }
    * html .ui-autocomplete { height: 100px; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<form name="frmSearch" runat="server">
    <div style="font:15px Arial;" >
    <b>Members</b>:  <input id="txtMembers1" type="text" runat="server" />
   <%--<b>Members</b>:  <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembers" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>--%>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also paste the output from your service? Assuming that response from service an array of strings, can you try modifying success function just to return response(data);

Comment: da
search1 (55,17)
dar
search1 (55,17)
[object Object]
search1 (68,25)
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      d: [ ]
   }

[object Object]
search1 (68,25)
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      d: [ ]
   }

ly
search1 (55,17)
[object Object]
search1 (68,25)
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      d: [
         0: "Lyles",
         1: "Lyles",
         2: "Lyles",
         length: 3
      ]
   }

Comment: so, the property that has the array is d. Shouldn't you be accessing it using data.d and then mapping it? 
Like - response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item }
                    }))

Comment: We have a winner !!! Thanks so much... working now.

Comment: Awesome! I will post this as an answer, please mark my post as an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was working with a hard-coded array, my suspicion was on the response format from your web service. As I got to know from the comments that property 'd' in your response holds the data array, hence you should be mapping data.d instead of data in your response.

```
response($.map(data.d, function (item) { return { value: item } }))
```